# Client-side linking of plotly chart and DT table

Tags: dt, r-plotly

I am trying to adapt an example from Carson Sievert's [plotly book](https://plotly-r.com/client-side-linking.html), where he links a leaflet map to a data-frame, so that it works for a plotly chart instead

```
 library(plotly)
 library(crosstalk)
 library(sf)

 nc <- sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"), quiet = TRUE)
 df <- nc %>% 
     select(AREA,NAME) %>% 
     group_by(NAME)

 st_geometry(df) <- NULL

 hk <- highlight_key(df)

chart <-plot_ly(df, y= ~NAME,x= ~AREA, split = ~NAME) %>%
       highlight() %>%
       layout(showlegend = FALSE) 

  bscols(chart, DT::datatable(hk))
```

This produces the required chart and data for every row, but clicking on a value
on the chart does not filter the data-table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide `hk` to both the plotly chart and the dt table. Also, I'd recommend adding `layout(barmode = "overlay")` the bar chart definition

Comment: Thanks for this but I am having trouble understanding what you mean by 'provide hk to the plotly chart' Would you mind revising the above code so that it works. Cheers

Comment: Change `plot_ly(df, y= ~NAME,x= ~AREA, split = ~NAME)` to `plot_ly(hk, split = ~NAME)`

Comment: Thanks. I still seem to need the x and y variables for the chart to show though

Comment: i.e plot_ly(hk, y= ~NAME,x= ~AREA, split = ~NAME)